# EditText must have at least 10 characters?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, min

I am a new developer on Android and Java. How can I make at least 10 characters in EditText ? Also, when the user enter a value less than 10, the application send an error message on screen. How can I do these ? [ edittext > = 10 ]

Comment: edittext.getText.toString.length() >= 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(YOUR_EDITTEXT);
    String s = et.getText().toString();
    if(s.length() <= 10){
        et.setError("Must exceed 10 characters!");
    } else {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: _at least 10 characters_ = _input length >= 10_

Comment: @Gooey I tried to your answer, but it has an error. "The method setError(String) is undefined for type String. "

Comment: @ogulcan1912 the method setError should be applied to your EditText, not the string.

Comment: It'w working.. final String emailstr = email.getText().toString();if(emailstr.length()==0)

            {
       //emailstr.requestFocus();
       email.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty string", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in several ways, but you can try this way:

```
 if (myEditText.getText().length() < minLength) {
     //Your message to there is no enough caracters
     } else {
         //Your action if it is satisfied.
     }
```

You can set minLenght to 10, or whatever, or simply ask if value is less than 10.

I hope that you get idea from this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use text watcher to check the user input and decide what to do inside

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);   
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can validate your `TextView` and if it doesn't fit your requirements, use `myTextView.setError(String)` to show an error.

If not you will have to implement `myTextView.addTextChangedListener(...)` and do things manually.

Hope it helps.